# Ionic: Sticky button at the bottom of a particular ion-slide

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am generating a bunch of slides with questions; The last slide is an overview of the previous answered questions. On the bottom I have a submit button that I want to always be visible on that (last) slide at the bottom of the page.

I tried the following:

- Use a ion-fab-button, which doesnt stick.
- Use CSS with "position: sticky !important;" on the button
- Wrap everything but the button in a ion-card-content

```
<ion-slide>
    <ion-card>
      <h1>Questions Overview</h1>
      <ion-list *ngFor="let question of questions">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>
            Question: {{ question.question }}
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>
            Your Answer: {{ question.answer }}
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
      <ion-button (click)="onSubmit()" expand="full">Submit</ion-button>
   </ion-card>
</ion-slide>
```

I am not that experienced in the framework so I dont if there is something else I could try.

When using google I only found questions and answers about buttons outside of ion-content. This doesnt help since everything used on the page is in ion-content and if I would do it this way the button will also be shown on all the other slides.

Edit:

TL;DR Workaround:

`@ViewChild('slides', {read: IonSlides}) slides: IonSlides;` in .ts file

Use Event `(ionSlideReachEnd)="onEnd()"` on `<ion-slides>` in .html

```
onEnd() {
  this.slides.isEnd().then(endReached => { 
  this.reachedEnd = endReached // reachedEnd is a variable that can be checked in the html file
}
```

I have used a workaround until I find a proper solution. I use the above used code to check if I have reached the end of my slides. After this I display a ion-footer which contains the button. The footer is stickied on the bottom of the page and not to the slides like I want to have it. The additional bonus is that now the user always has the ability to submit on any slide when reviewing his answers.

Answer (score 1):

A simple *ngIf can do the job for you... so we put the condition that the button will only be visible on the last slide, we know that the array index of the last slide will be equal to the length of the array -1... hence we put the condition: `<ion-button *ngIf='idx==questions.length-1' (click)="onSubmit()" expand="full">Submit</ion-button>`

relevant **HTML**:

```
<ion-content padding>

    <ion-slides>
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let question of questions; let idx = index">
            <ion-card>
                <h1>Questions Overview</h1>
                <ion-list>
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label>
                            Question: {{ question.question }}
                        </ion-label>
                    </ion-item>
                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label>
                            Your Answer: {{ question.answer }}
                        </ion-label>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-list>
                <ion-button *ngIf='idx==questions.length-1' (click)="onSubmit()" expand="full" style='border:2px solid red;padding:5px; margin:5px; background:lightpink; position: absolute; bottom: 0%; left:50%; margin-left:-17px'>Submit</ion-button>
            </ion-card>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>

</ion-content>
```

check the about tab on the [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-sckjg2)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesnt answer my question. I want the button to be stickied on the bottom of the page like it would be on an ion-footer but only on the last slide.

Comment: @PatrickJung, Hi, take a look at updated stackblitz... relevant line is: `<ion-button *ngIf='idx==questions.length-1' (click)="onSubmit()" expand="full" style='border:2px solid red;padding:5px; margin:5px; background:lightpink; position: absolute; bottom: 10px;'>Submit</ion-button>`

Comment: It is almost working, but this way the button sticks to the slide and not the view of the user/device

Comment: Testing with your stackblitz, in dont know why the slides are not scrollable in the stackblitz when you add more content in it. Also in my project I use this piece of css in the scss file: ion-slides `ion-slide {
     display: block;
 }`

Comment: this should fix that for you `<ion-button *ngIf='idx==questions.length-1' (click)="onSubmit()" expand="full" style='border:2px solid red;padding:5px; margin:5px; background:lightpink; position: absolute; bottom: 0%; left:50%; margin-left:-17px'>Submit</ion-button>` ... it is working for me on different resolutions... in case of any styling issue, can you share screenshot?

Comment: Thats not working either. I would like to provide a modified version of your stackblitz but the slide is for some reason not able do be scrollable so I cant reproduce the problem i have in that case.

Comment: your scrollable issue is also resolved in the updated stackblitz code... is it working for you now ?

Comment: No if you add more content to the ion list the list is still not scrollable in the stackblitz. I appreciate the help you provided so far but I dont think it is possible the way I want to use it with the slides. I have to rethink how I want to display the submit button.

Maybe I should ask this question directly on the ionic framework forum.

Comment: can you fork my stackblitz (https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-sckjg2)... then make your changes so that we can troubleshoot

Comment: I did a workaround. I have a ion-footer now that will show up when the event `ionSlideReachEnd` gets triggered. This event triggers a function that checks again if the end is reached with the `isEnd()` function from IonSlides